# Simple line chart joining top of histograms

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

In the following example I mapped histograms on letter vs frequency. Now, I want a line chart also for the same data without making much change. This means just a red line joining top of histograms. Can someone help me out?

```
<html>

<head> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script> 

</head>

<body> 

<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>

<script>

//Our basic data 
var data = [
    {frequency:0.08, letter:"A"},
    {frequency:0.11,letter:"B"},
    {frequency:0.13,letter:"C"}
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var margin = {top: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40, right: 40};
var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.6);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

//defining our main g in svg 
var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Looping for data bars 
data.forEach(function(){

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

    g
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    g
        .append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"));

    g
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

});

</script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**HISTOGRAM:**

[image]

Comment: @Lars-Kotthoff : can you answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get rid of that `data.forEach`: why do you want to paint everything 3 times?

After that, define your line generator:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d){ return x(d.letter) + x.bandwidth()/2})
    .y(function(d){ return y(d.frequency)})
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);;
```

Here, `x.bandwidth()/2` will put the line in the middle of the top of each bar. I'm using `d3.curveCardinal`, but you have [other options](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curves) for the curve.

Then, append the line:

```
g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", line);
```

Here is the demo:

```html
<head> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script> 

</head>

<body> 

<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>

<script>

//Our basic data 
var data = [
    {frequency:0.08, letter:"A"},
    {frequency:0.11,letter:"B"},
    {frequency:0.13,letter:"C"}
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var margin = {top: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40, right: 40};
var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.6);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

//defining our main g in svg 
var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Looping for data bars 


    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
  
  var line = d3.line()
   .x(function(d){ return x(d.letter) + x.bandwidth()/2})
   .y(function(d){ return y(d.frequency)})
        .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

    g
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    g
        .append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"));

    g
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
    
    g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("fill", "none");


</script>
```